# Lenovo B50-70 Electric Shock when touching VGA port , when plugged to AC

Tags: vga, electric-shock

Recently bought Lenovo B50-70 (2 days), connected it to AC with three pin adapter given. Accidently touched the vga port and I got a serious jolt. Vga Ports are OK. When using on battery I don't have this issue. Can this be rectified or should I get this laptop replaced.

Comment: That is a serious defect, and one the manufacturer should fix.  Even if it isn't under warranty, manufacturers usually recall products with flaws for which they could be sued or receive bad press.

Comment: Do you only get shocked when barefoot on the ground or otherwise touching a grounded surface?  Does wearing insulating shoes make the problem disappear?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/462244/electric-shock-mild-vibrating-sensation-on-macbook-pro-when-charging?rq=1

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the laptop itself and no need to replace it (if the AC adapter was truly leaking mains voltage to the laptop then it probably would've ended up in flames), check the link posted by @ShaneDiDona for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should almost certainly get this replaced.

Consider weather it's under warranty or not, but the cost & risk is probably outweighed the time and effort of self repair.